# Not able to see fields on PayPal Layout C

Tags: web-services, paypal, salesforce

I am onlt getting three fields in layout c in manager paypal(payflow api) on my site. How i can add other fields like name,address ,email phone etc. Fields which I am able to see are : Card Number,Expiration date and CSC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Layout Posts that data directly to PayPal to ease your PCI compliance responsibility. you can collect the rest if the information in your own form before checkout. [Hosted Checkout Pages](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#hosted-checkout-pages) will provide an overview of how it works.